# MongoDB how to find record with "second level" value

Tags: mongodb

I have a JSON format like this

```
{"id":123,"person":{"name":"test","age":123,"address":"test"}}
```

How to find the record use id and person name?

I tried the following:

```
db.test.find({"id":123,"person":{"name":"test"}})
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, notice the `person.name` piece that is different than the question:

```
db.test.find({"id":123,"person.name":"test"})
```

Comment: Is this the answer, another part of the question or something else? A little more context around a line of code could help others.